# removing characters from php output in xml

Tags: php, xml, magento, google-shopping

I have written a xml/php document that is pulling from a Magento Commerce database, to create the XML document with all of the items in it, so that Google's Shopping can import the items. Google's system is getting hung up on a item, I believe that this is due to the special characters. I want to strip those characters out of the output. Notice in the output that there is a couple of registered trademarks, and some quotes, and commas. I doubt the quotes or commas are the problem, I think it may be the trademarks.

Here is the output

```
<title>The FoamZall - Spray Foam Insulation Trimming Foam Saw - w/ Open Cell Blade</title>
<description>The FOAMZALL includes the toughest Milwaukee® brand heavy-duty orbital Sawzall® around, which has a custom coupling to secure a 36" long serrated blade intended for trimming 1/2 lb and 2 LB foam.  The 13 Amp, 120 Vac saw has a 1 1/4" stroke and can provide up to 3,000 strokes per minute.  Carry case is included.   </description>
<g:google_product_category>Business &amp; Industrial &gt; Construction</g:google_product_category>
<g:product_type>Spray Foam Parts &amp; Supplies &gt; Fusion AP Parts</g:product_type>
<link>http://sprayfoamsys.com/store/the-foamzall-spray-foam-insulation-trimming-saw-open-cell-blade.html</link>
<g:image_link>http://sprayfoamsys.com/store/media/catalog/product/f/o/foamzall.jpg</g:image_link>
<g:condition>new</g:condition>
<g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
<g:price>425.0000</g:price>
<g:brand></g:brand>
<g:mpn></g:mpn>
</item>
<item>
```

My Script is:

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" ?>'; ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:c="http://www.base.google.com/cns/1.0">
<channel>
<title>Spray Foam Systems</title>
<link>http://www.sprayfoamsys.com/store/</link>
<description>Spray Foam Rigs, Spray Foam Equipment, Sprayfoam Parts and Supplies.</description>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect(REMOVED) or die(mysql_error());
    if (!$con)
        {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    mysql_select_db("sprayfoa_store", $con);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` WHERE `visibility` = 4 ORDER BY entity_id asc")
    or die(mysql_error());
?>
<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
?>
<item>
<g:id><?php echo $row['entity_id']; ?></g:id>
<title><?php echo $row['name']; ?></title>
<description><?php echo (str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n"), ' ', $row['short_description'])); ?></description>
<g:google_product_category>Business &amp; Industrial &gt; Construction</g:google_product_category>
<g:product_type>Spray Foam Parts &amp; Supplies &gt; Fusion AP Parts</g:product_type>
<link>http://sprayfoamsys.com/store/<?php echo $row['url_path']; ?></link>
<g:image_link>http://sprayfoamsys.com/store/media/catalog/product<?php echo $row['small_image']; ?></g:image_link>
<g:condition>new</g:condition>
<g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
<g:price><?php echo $row['price']; ?></g:price>
<g:brand><?php $entity_id = $row['entity_id']; $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` WHERE entity_id = '$entity_id' AND attribute_id = '127'") or die(mysql_error()); while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) { echo $row2['value']; } ?></g:brand>
<g:mpn><?php echo $row['sku']; ?></g:mpn>
</item>
<?php
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Hm, haven't encountered it before. Do you specify a character set in your XML? What character set are you sending? And if it isn't utf-8, could you try that one?

Comment: The error I get is an XML formatting error - Line 205 Column 559, line 205 is the `<description>` tag

Comment: Which encoding is the XML? Which encoding are the variables you get from the database? What is the XML output where it fails? Which encoding is valid for the google service? Why don't you use XML writer?

Comment: will it work when you change the prolog to `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`?

Comment: @hakre - the XML is now utf-8, I am unsure of the encoding from the database, the xml output line that fails is now line 121 col 330, here is the line `<description>The FOAMZALL includes the toughest Milwaukee� brand heavy-duty orbital Sawzall� around, which has a custom coupling to secure a 36" long serrated blade intended for trimming 1/2 lb and 2 LB foam.  The 13 Amp, 120 Vac saw has a 1 1/4" stroke and can provide up to 3,000 strokes per minute.  Carry case is included.   </description>`. I am unsure of the accepted encoding for google shopping.

Comment: @hakre cont. - I didn't use a writer because I have never used one, heard of one, and am unfamiliar with how they work. I am pulling directly from a database, can a writer do this?

Comment: @Gordon - I tried adding the utf-8 encoding, I now get a ton of encoding errors. view link http://sprayfoamsys.com/product-feed.xml

Comment: Make your database client return UTF-8 as well. That's a database connection setting, afterwards all problems might be solved already. The important part is that you know the character encoding.

Comment: I am not sure how to set that as a connection setting. Can you tell me how that would be done?

Comment: I used phpMyAdmin to access and view my database structure, the fields I am pulling from are showing a collation of `utf8_general_ci`does this help?

Comment: OK I figured out how to set the database connection setting to utf-8 by using `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $con);`, it pushed my further, but now a `&` is messing me up, I am going to try converting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure any characters outside the 0-255 range should be encoded as `&#___;`.

Comment: that's wrong for XML, only some very few need entities and some characters just don't exist (like \x00). Most characters work if the document is properly encoded, e.g. UTF-8 is default for XML.

Comment: That may be, but there may be restrictions on the API. Perhaps it only accepts documents in `iso-8859-1`, for instance.

Comment: then there would be no characters outside of 0-255 anyway, however same for that encoding: some of those your answers says are valid aren't and the rest wouldn't need entities.